# Find the matching file from A1 and change the file's name to the new name/string in cell B1

Tags: excel, vba, nested-loops, offset, file-rename

I have to change all our filenames to the company's new nomenclature, since we are uploading the old One Drive files onto SharePoint. I have to do this for about 60 folders, each with eight to ten subfolders. It's hundreds of files. I'm the one who wrote the new nomenclature rules, because all the different versions named by different teams over the last 20 years is driving me crazy. So far, I can get a list of the file names in each folder. I have an Excel spreadsheet for each top-level folder that lists all its current filenames in Column 1 (because my department is going to keep using them. Sigh...) and the new standardized name in Column 2. This document is going to be like the Rosetta Stone of our archives. But how can I actually loop through all the files in all the folders to apply all these new names? I need a module that will rename each specified file according to the spreadsheet.

I am pretty new to VBA. I have tried several codes I found online, but they aren't specific to what I am doing, so they aren't working, LOL. I have tried Dir and I have the Scripting Running for Early Binding and I've tried a couple thing that look like this:

```
Sub Rename_Files()
    Dim SourcePath As String, Fname As String, NewFName As String
    Dim i As Long
    SourcePath = "C:\QuarterlyReports\"
    For i = 1 To 100
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
    NewFName = Range("B" & i).Value
    'Search for the first file containing the string in column A
    Fname = Dir(SourcePath & "*" & Range("A" & i).Value & "*")
    If Fname <> vbNullString Then
    FileCopy SourcePath & Fname, DestPath & NewFName
    Else
    MsgBox Range("A" & i).Value & " Not Exists in Folder"
    End If
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But I need the file name to be changed accordingly and I don't know how to do that. Frankly, I'm lost.

Comment: can you retrieve the fullname and placed it in column 1? fullname meaning the path and the filename itself ex: `C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\sample files\data file.xlsx`

Comment: Dir not search subfolders and to get the next match a new Dir command is needed with no arguments. You can use Scripting.FileSystemObject

Comment: will this work?Sub Rename_Files_in_Folder() 'Loop through and rename all files in a folder

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject Dim fo As Folder Dim f As File Dim last_row As Integer

last_row = Worksheets("Sheetl").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set fo = fso.GetFolder("D:\Users\folder\ files")

Dim new_name As String For Each f In fo.Files For i = 3 To last_row If f.Name = Worksheets("Sheetl").Cells(i, 1).Value Then new_name = Worksheets("Sheetl").Cells(i, 2).Value f.Name = new_name End If Next Next MsgBox "Task Completed"

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
This works great!

```vbs
Sub RenameFiles()

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo As folder
    Dim f As File
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row'
    Set fo = folder`
    fso.GetFolder("D:\Users\me\Downloads\foldername\")
    Dim newname As String
    
    For Each f In fo.Files
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            If f.Name = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                newname = Cells(i, 2).Value
                f.Name = newname
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    MsgBox "All Files Are Now Renamed"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a typo: `Set fo = folder`. You want `Set fo = fso.GetFolder("D:\Users\me\Downloads\foldername\")`. Pls. edit it for the future visitors, and if it works as you desired, mark it as accepted (icon under voting).